How can I create a multi-step form using Elementor without using additional plugins?
I'm working on a project where I need to create a multi-step form using Elementor, but I want to avoid using additional plugins. I need each step of the form to be user-friendly and visually appealing, ensuring a smooth transition between steps. I'm looking for a detailed guide or best practices on how to achieve this within Elementor's native capabilities.

You can see how to achieve this in the Elementor documentation: Create a multistep form
You'll need Elementor Pro to be able to use the form widget.

You can use Jquery with CSS and apply conditions based on Field classes to get the result in elementor (If you dont have paid version) for next step you can add HTML field and add buttons (Next) and apply jQuery on buttons to get the results
